# Get/Set Springboard Icon Layout within an App

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, iphone-privateapi

I'm trying to make an app that can "snapshot" the layout of the SpringBoard icon layouts, and then restore those at a later time. I know this will need the private framework and won't be able to put on the App Store. I also want this to work for non-jailbroken devices.

I've looked at the iOS 9 private framework headers, and I see SpringBoardService.framework, but no clear way to get and set the icon layout. I'm not even sure how they are represented in there or if that's the right class.

I also found this post about a file on the filesystem that can be updated to change the layout: http://forums.imore.com/iphone-apps-games/308394-how-save-ios-icon-folder-layout-information-home-screen-ios-8-a.html

Ideally, it would make sense to just save/overwrite that file and respring, but I haven't seen any way to access the private filesystem outside of a jailbreak.

Anyone have any ideas on how best to implement this kind of functionality? Obviously I'm not well versed in the private frameworks, especially not for iOS 9.

Comment: I can send you some info I received by email from one of the devs with this regard. But I cant post it here publically

Comment: Oh man that would be great. Really scratching my head with it since there is no documentation. You can email it to me here: 27ih8p+9563y5uobnqf4@grr.la

Comment: @jtjenkins I have to implement the same, have you found any solution of implementing this?